# WCF: может ли метод имет несколько параметров Stream?

Tags: потоки-данных, wcf, .net-4.0

- ### `.Net 4.0`

Сериализуемый `class A` вынесен в `A.dll` для возможности использования типа сервером и клиентом.
Использовать данный тип в параметрах методов службы нельзя.

---

- ### `MemoryStream`

У `WCF` службы есть метод:

```
bool Method1(Stream InA, ref Stream OutA);
```

где `InA` - входной параметр, сериализованный в двоичном формате (см. [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)) объект типа `A`;
`OutA` - выходной параметр, того же типа.

- Клиент, перед вызовом метода, сериализует объект `A` в `MemoryStream` и отправляет серверу.
- Сервер десериализует `InA`, обрабатывает его, полученный результат сериализует в `OutA`.
- Клиент десериализует `OutA`, получает новый объект.

При тестировании службы на локальном `IIS`, работает. После публикации на сервер, клиент, при попытке вызова метода, выдает ошибку:

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:InOrderNumberStream. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.IO.MemoryStream. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 44030.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

---

- ### `Stream`

Если тип параметра `Stream` заменить на `MemoryStream`:

```
bool Method1(MemoryStream InA, ref MemoryStream OutA);
```

проект компилируется без ошибок, но при запуске службы `IIS` выдает ошибку:

```
Чтобы запрос в операции NewCalculation был потоком, операция должна иметь один параметр с типом Stream.
```

[Читал](http://www.tmy.mwport.ru/files/2011-2-tech-21.pdf), что:
*Функция, принимающая экземпляр класса Stream в качестве параметра, не может иметь дополнительных параметров.*

---

1. Не понятно, почему со `Stream` можно
   только один параметр объявлять, а с
   `MemoryStream` можно больше?
2. После сериализации объект `A` в
   `Stream` занимает ~28 КБ. Если не
   ошибаюсь, по `Stream` можно
   передавать очень большие объемы
   данных? Все таки, через 
   `MemoryStream` тоже, можно только
   один параметр описать?
3. Можно ли использовать другие
   stream'ы (`MemoryStream`,
   `FileStream`, ...), кроме `Stream`?
4. Как добиться, что бы метод
   принимал `A` и возвращал `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустимо использовать только один параметр `Stream`. В качестве возвращаемого тип можно использовать `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

а почему вы не делаете так:
Stream Method1(Stream InA);

???